# Send JPanel through Java UDP Networking

Tags: java, swing, sockets, networking, udp

I have a very basic video game written in Java where all the graphics are displayed in a `JPanel`. I wish to use UDP Networking to implement a multiplayer feature to this game. To do, one of the basic things I need to be able to do is to send and receive a `JPanel` with the correct graphics between a client and server using UDP.

I have looked through other questions and tutorials using Java UDP Networking to get an idea of how UDP works, but I am still not quite sure how I would implement a program that sends a `JPanel` with the proper graphics inside it from client to server and vice versa using UDP?

Is there any advice that someone could give me? Maybe there is a question incredibly similar to this that I just missed when researching?

Thank you!

Comment: Components obtain a connection to the native peer of the current computer, transmitting components to another computer will confuse the component and result in unexpected and unusual errors - don't do this! The size of the component would also be considerable large when compared to the information it actually needs to render the current state.  Better to send the state, as it will be faster to transmit

Answer (score 4):

> To do, one of the basic things I need to be able to do is to send and receive a JPanel with the correct graphics between a client and server using UDP.

This is exactly what I recommend that you don't do. Instead, I strongly urge you to send model state, not view display, over your network, and then allow each site to use the model state to construct its own view. Doing it this way will be **much** more efficient as you'd be sending a much smaller dataset online. But note that if you do this, then you might need to use a more reliable transmission protocol than UDP such as TCP (although not necessarily).

Whether you send the data through UDP or TCP will depend on which is more critical for your game: network speed or absolute data integrity. The network communication is usually the tightest bottleneck. Your desire to send a serialized JPanel means that you'd be sending thousands of data bits over the network where only a few bits are needed.

Comment: By model state, do you mean the state of the game that is shown in the JPanel? And so I should send the game's state through a UDP network and then construct its own JPanel using the state of the game that was given?

Like for instance, if i had a JPanel of a green ball, and it moved to the right 100 pixels and I sent that over the UDP network, I should send the state of the green ball in the game (like its new position)? And then when received I can take that information and display the green ball on a new JPanel with its new position?

Comment: @Midgar77: yes, the state of the game. Whether you send it through UDP or TCP will depend on which is more critical for your game: network speed or absolute data integrity. The network communication is usually the tightest bottleneck. Your desire to send a serialized JPanel means that you'd be sending thousands of data bits over the network where only a few bits are needed.